# Plot curve with multiple parameters

Tags: r, plot, probability, curve

I want to make a plot using `curve` for multiple parameters.

For example, say I have the following distribution function for the binomial distribution:

[image]

I can plot curve for a probability mass function likeso:

```
curve(factorial(10)/(factorial(5)*factorial(5))*y^5*(1-y)^5, from=0, to = 1)
```

Because we want 0 < y < 1, however this won't work for multiple variables as `from = 0, to = 1` will only apply for a single variable.

So - how can I get curve to work for something like:

```
curve(factorial(10)/(factorial(10-x)*factorial(x))*y^x*(1-y)^{10-x}, from=0, to = 1)
```

But also to indicate the the distribution function for x is less than or equal to 5, so `from = 0, to = 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `dbinom` directly

```
curve(dbinom(5, 10, y), xname = "y")
```

[image]

or if you need to vary `x`, you can try

```
sapply(0:10, function(k) curve(dbinom(k, 10, y), xname = "y", add = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: `pbinom` works better in my case as it's specifically for the distribution function. Thanks for showing me that it works! because there are many available distributions for this on R that I can implement alongside this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over a sequence from 0 to 5.

```
curve(factorial(10)/(factorial(5)*factorial(5))*x^5*(1-x)^5, from=0, to=1, 
      ylim=c(0, 1), type='n')
invisible(lapply(seq.int(.005, 5, .005), \(y) 
       curve(factorial(10)/(factorial(10 - x)*factorial(x))*y^x*(1 - y)^{10 - x}, 
             add=TRUE))
)
```

The `invisible` avoids cluttering of the console.

[image]